# Can you recovered delete folders with sublime text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

I think i've deleted a whole folder by accident in sublime text 2. Is it possible to recover this deleted folder? I've checked my trash and nothing.

Using windows 7.

Comment: Unless you've been making regular backups (you do, don't you?), you're out of luck. Depending on exactly what you did to delete the directory (I'm assuming through the side bar somehow), Python's [`shutil.rmtree()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) function is called, which bypasses the Windows Recycle Bin. If you immediately halt your computer and run a forensic recovery tool on it you might be able to recover some of the lost data if it hasn't been written over, but the sooner you act the better. Good luck!

Comment: This would be a good point to install the "SideBar Enhancements" plugin using package control.

Answer (score -13, accepted):

Its gone buddy ! I did something similar and couldn't retrieve a file. 
Anyway, not sure if it is going to help you but I wrote a simple SLT-plugin to back up *modified* files (locally and remote).

Local backup plugin:

```
class RemoteEdit(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
def on_post_save(self, view):
    os.system('cp -r %s %s' % (view.file_name(), <backup_path>)) #use scp for remote backup
```

Answer (score 86):

Same thing just happened to me.

Not to worry! Sublime does not permanently delete your files, but only moves them to trash (Recycle Bin). You will find your hard work sitting right there :)

See [this reference](https://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/52849-prompt-for-delete-a-file/) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily recover it from Trash / Recycle Bin folder on your machine.
Sublime or any other third party software never delete files permanently, in case of windows, it catches deleted files and move it to Recycle Bin.

Comment: As far as I can tell, prior to BUILD 2165, 12 January 2012 Sublime Text did indeed avoid using Trash and deleted permanently.  You are right though that more recent versions (and you should probably be using Sublime Text 3) do send to Trash.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't find in trash as in my case you can use "restore-trash" utility on linux. It can be installed using following command

> sudo apt install trash-cli

After installing open command line and navigate to the folder.

Enter command

> restore-trash

Choose the file which you wish to restore

Answer (score -2):

If you are on windows, You can look at Recycle Bin.
Otherwise not possible without any advance tool.